# Modify the name of the elements only if they appear in the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let it be the following Python Pandas DataFrame.

| ID | region |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | FRA |
| 99 | GER |
| 13 | ESP |
| 69 | UK |
| 17 | GER |
| 02 | GER |

Using the next code:

```
dictionary = {'GER': 'Germany', 'FRA': 'France'}
df['region'] = df['region'].map(dictionary)
```

I get the following result:

| ID | region |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | France |
| 99 | Germany |
| 13 | NaN |
| 69 | NaN |
| 17 | Germany |
| 02 | Germany |

My idea is that the values that do not appear in the dictionary, keep their previous values.

| ID | region |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | France |
| 99 | Germany |
| 13 | ESP |
| 69 | UK |
| 17 | Germany |
| 02 | Germany |

How could I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is that :

```
df.replace({"region": dictionary})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) (or [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html)):

```
df['region'] = df['region'].map(dictionary).fillna(df['region'])
```

or take advantage of the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to set the value as default:

```
df['region'] = df['region'].map(lambda x: dictionary.get(x, x))
```

output:

```
   ID   region
0  12   France
1  99  Germany
2  13      ESP
3  69       UK
4  17  Germany
5   2  Germany
```